# Task manager can't find the process

Tags: windows-7, windows, steam

I launched a game call Dirty Bomb but it crashed.
My steam told me I was still playing it.
I shutdown my PC and turned it back on to find that I was *still playing dirty bomb*.
I couldn't find the process using Task manager.
I clicked on the details tab and saw the file
`Shootergame-Win32-Shipping` and the description was Dirty Bomb.
I tried ending the task and got the error:

> Unable to terminate process this operation could not be completed. Access is denied"

I'm an admin on my PC and the only one who uses it.

---

I made a video regarding the problem
Sorry about the quality..
and the fact i filmed it with bandicam..
when i went into my msconfig i was trying tn emphasize that nothing was out of the ordinary.
https://youtu.be/MHwhQoH1yZg -Future me

Comment: I spent about an hour looking for solutions before posting the question, it doesn't pop up under startup in task manger, and i cant close out of it in process explorer either.

Comment: Are you sure its not a virus? and when you post a question, be simple. just ask what you have simply without this much data.

Comment: Can you rename the offending file so it just doesn't load? .. or copy it somewhere "safe" and then delete the original? This would help prevent it from loading on start up if it is indeed some sort of malware or virus

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help me solve my problem.
I ended up starting my pc in safe mode and uninstalling the program.
Don't know where my brain was...
I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a full antivirus scan if possible as a matter of course, (you should do this regularly anyway) but try opening System Configuration (press Windows Key+R and type "msconfig.exe" without quotes and press the Enter key) and disabling any un-necessary startup programs. If you have found the name of the process in Task Manager look for that program first, but whilst you're there, disable any non-Microsoft program you don't think you need; you can always re-enable it if you do find you need it to run at startup.

Then try restarting the system and see if the problem's still there. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't believe its a virus because i run scans frequently (and i quite trust steam) but i have disabled a few startup programs and i hope to see it works, ill get back to you.

Comment: Rebooted, this didnt seem to have fixed it but thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Run tools like [Process exploer](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip) to see the process thread & find out what spawned it

[PsKill](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip) is another utility from **Windows Sysinternal** that can be used in such scenarios to get rid of zombie processes

Comment: I have used Process explorer, that didn't work but i'll check out PsKill Thanks!